# Strange error when releasing a new package version: Cannot modify managed object: entity=PackageIntegerValue

Tags: feature-management, 2gmp

I have custom feature parameters in my application. However, I haven't modified them but still I received the following error

> Message delivering: CustomFeatureParameter: Cannot modify managed
> object: entity=PackageIntegerValue, component=9NV1j0000008zFA,
> state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: DataflowDirection Previous Value:
> Abonnent an LMO New Value: Subscriber To LMO,

and a long list of all of my custom feature parameters repeating the error text.

What is going on and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told this is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001nzrYQAQ)

I have found the following workaround:

Include

```
"country" : "de",
"language": "en",
```

into a file project-scratch-def.json

Comment: One of those scenarios where Salesforce unfortunately uses the label value instead of an API name, so you need to make sure the same language is used every time you create a version...

Comment: yes, I understand. My PBO was mistakenly created with a DE, this has been fixed recently but all my packages have been broken because of that...

Comment: Don't get me wrong; Salesforce made a boo-boo here and really should fix it. I was just trying to highlight why the workaround would work.

Comment: @Patlatus did you manage this? Seems like we have the same problem :(

Comment: @EugeneVabishchevich I used a workaround and I can see the known issue is still under review. You may subscribe to the known issue or open salesforce support ticket to inform Salesforce that you are also affected.

Comment: @Patlatus yeap, I already subscribed :) For the project-scratch-def.json file: I don't think it matters for the new version creation. Does it?

Comment: Actually it does